# Should we use <h1> for site name on header?

Tags: html

I learned about the use of headings <h1-h6>. We suggested to only use one <h1> on every page. The question is: should I use <h1> for only the site name on the header, such as "Quercia's Company Website"? Does it mean I can't use <h1> for the important title on the article I make on the page? or it will better if I use <p> for the site name, so I can use <h1> for every article's title?

Thanks so much!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to follow SEO (Search Engine Optimization) best practices it is best to only use one `<h1>` tag per page (page title). You can have multiple `<h2>`, `<h3>`, etc. tags. For example if you are making a page about articles you can have a `<h1>` tag that is for articles, and and `<h2>` for article titles.

I recommend doing some research on SEO to get a better understanding of it all. Of course this would only matter if your site is going live.

Hope this helps!